# LESS Hover an item apply styling to different elements

Tags: html, css, less

I have four words, when I hover over the first one I want also the second one light up in another color.

```
 #one {
cursor:pointer;
&:hover {
  #one {
  color:red;
  }
  #two {
  color:red;
  }
}
```

I thought this was it, but apparently  it doesn't work :(

here a small codepen.

http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/NGWXzQ

Comment: "apperently it doesnt work" Please clarify on what this does, vs what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats what you want:

```
#one {
  cursor:pointer;
  &:hover {
    color:red;
    ~ #two {
    color:red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exacly what I want, didnt know ~ did something

Comment: ~ selects a sibling on the same dom-level, you searched for #two as a child of #one

Comment: Ye I see now. In sass it works but I need to use Less at the moment , I was kinda confused when it didn't work :)

Comment: @Dennis "In sass it works" - For your original snippet both Less and SCSS produce *identical* CSS, so in this case you're cheating yourself.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I know, but im used to SASS that's why I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
body {
  background-color:#161616;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 #one{
   color:black;
   cursor:pointer;}
  #one:hover{
    color:red;
    }
 #two{
   color:black;
   cursor:pointer;}
  #two:hover{
    color:red;
    }
 #three{
   color:black;
   cursor:pointer;}
  #three:hover{
    color:red;
    }
 #four{
   color:black;
   cursor:pointer;}
  #four:hover{
    color:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="center">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
    <div id="four">four</div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the sibling selector. Although you should keep an eye out for browser compatibility.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Check out this pen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjWaRj

```
#one {
 cursor:pointer;
 &:hover {
  color:green;
  + #two {
   color:red;
  }
 }
}
```